# Animation in UITableViewCell breaks after cell deallocation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an expanding view in the cell. After i press show more button it works fine. But when i scroll down and that cell deallocates from memory and then i tap on show more button again animation breaks. How can i fix it?

[Project repo on Github](https://github.com/davidmorra/ExpandableViewInCell)

Collapsed view:
[image: Collapsed view]

Expanded view:
[image: Expanded view]

Debugger view, before scroll:
[image: Debugger view, before scroll]

After cell deallocation (after scroll) breaks like this, expands behind second cell:
[image: After cell deallocation (after scroll) breaks like this, expands behind second cell]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Do you want your "expand cell" to **cover** the cells below it? Or, do you want it to expand and "push the other cells down"?

Comment: just to expand and cover, without pushing other cells and it works fine until you scroll down and deallocate cell from memory, then it no longer expands like it did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code and comment...

Instead of expanding your **cell**, you're setting `clipsToBounds = false` and expanding the cell's *contents*, allowing them to extend outside the bounds of the cell.

As you scroll a `UITableView`, cells are - of course - added / removed as needed. But when they are re-added, the "z-order" changes (because, with "standard" table view usage, it doesn't matter).

So, after scrolling down and then back up, and then tapping the "Show more" button, that cell may be (and usually is) at a *lower z-order* ... and thus its expanded "out-of-bounds" content is hidden ***behind*** the cell(s) below it.

If you want to stick with that approach (as opposed to expanding the cell itself), you can try implementing `scrollViewDidScroll` to make sure that cell is "on the top":

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    // make sure the first row is visible (not scrolled off the top of the view)
    let pth = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    if let a = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows,
       a.contains(pth),
       let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: pth) {
        // bring it to the front -- i.e. the top of the z-order
        tableView.bringSubviewToFront(c)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: great!! based on your explanation, just changed the first cells zPosition "cell.layer.zPosition = 99" like this and it also works, but looks weird in debugger. Anyway, thank you, saved a lot of time.